# Ready an attack to disrupt spellcaster + attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, concentration

A player can ready an action to attack a spellcaster within their reach when they want to cast anything.

And a player also gains an attack of opportunity if someone casts a spell within their reach, not defensively (or if the player has taken Spellcasting Harrier, which would trigger an attack of opportunity even if the caster is casting defensively).

So if a player ready an attack, and the caster is not casting defensively (or triggered AoO anyway), does this player make two attacks to that caster simultaneously, and the caster must make a concentration check with the sum of two attacks' damages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both readied action and attack of opportunity would be triggered, and so the caster would be attacked twice in a row.

No, they wouldn’t be “simultaneous,” that basically isn’t a thing within the game rules. There would first be one attack, and then the second attack. Which is first would depend on the wording of the readied attack’s trigger, the DM’s adjudication thereof, and however the table generally handles order of effects (this isn’t covered by the rules but the FAQ suggests using the controller’s preference as a rule of thumb, so in this case that’d be the player).

No, you would not add the attacks’ damage together to determine the Concentration check: the caster would simply have to make two Concentration checks, one at each appropriate DC. The readied attack and the attack of opportunity are separate “actions” in the context of the Concentration skill rules for damage taken.

In all cases, demonstrating these statements is hard, simply because they are all a matter of “nothing tells you to do otherwise.” There is no rule about attacks of opportunity and readied actions interfering with one another, so they would just both happen as normal. Likewise, there are no rules in play here that cause attacks to be “simultaneous” mechanically, nor are there general rules for what that would even mean, such as whether it would cause the two Concentration checks to be combined somehow. In the absence of any of those rules, everything just works as normal, separately. There isn’t really an interaction here.

Answer (score 3):

### You make two separate attacks

As per the rules on [Attacks of Opportunity](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/attacksOfOpportunity.htm)

> An attack of opportunity **"interrupts" the normal flow of actions** in the round. If an attack of opportunity is provoked, immediately resolve the attack of opportunity, **then** continue with the next character’s turn (or **complete the current turn, if the attack of opportunity was provoked in the midst of a character’s turn**).

Note that an attack of opportunity in itself is not any kind of action (e.g. it is not listed under any of the action types in the various tables of standard, move, full-round, free or miscellaneous actions). It is just a single attack.

And for Ready an Action

> You can ready a standard action, a move action, or a free action. To do so, specify the action you will take and the conditions under which you will take it. Then, any time before your next action, you may take the readied action in response to that condition. The action occurs **just before the action that triggers it**. If the triggered action is part of another character’s activities, you interrupt the other character.

These are two different attacks that in this case both are triggered by the target trying to cast a spell. Each is resolved separately, and each comes with its own, separate concentration check.

Also, because making an attack of opportunity is not an action itself, there is no conflict with having to take the readied action "before your next action", even if you conclude that the Attack of Opportunity happens first (which is not fully specified by the rules, see [Kryan's answer on that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206968/75095)).

Comment: “your […] action” was used, early in the edition, to mean “your turn” anyway, so even if an attack of opportunity **was** an action, it wouldn’t matter here.